# Enviar variable como parametro a Js

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy intentando pasar el valor de una variable en un select a través de un evento que llama un función, o

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="materials"  (change)="onChangeMaterial($event,m.data)">
      <option value="" disabled="true" [selected]="true">Seleccione una opción</option>
       <option *ngFor="let m of material" [id]="m.data"   [value]="m.id">{{m.label}}</option>
</select>


  onChangeMaterial($event, $alert) {
    console.log($event);
    this.materialVis = 'shown';
    this.tipoEmba = 'shown';
    this.docServ.package($event).subscribe(packages => {
        this.package = packages;
    }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

    if($alert == 1){
        this.addToast({
            title: 'Sustancia controlada',
            msg: 'El material que eligió es una sustancia controlada',
            timeout: 5000,
            theme: 'default',
            position: 'bottom-right',
            type: 'warning'
        });
     }
}
```

al recibirlo me genera el siguiente error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

¿Cómo puedo hacer para pasar el valor de esa variable o en su defecto el id para poder controlar la alerta

Comment: Tienes un atributo `formControlName`, así que asumo que tienes un formulario reactivo. ¿Por qué no te suscribes al formControl correspondiente?